# Compatibility Ubuntu Server and packages on ARM

Tags: webserver, arm, ubuntu-server

i'm working on a web server hosted on a board based on an ARM processor, that is named UDOO (http://www.udoo.org) and is similar to the Raspberry PI, and on it you can install a version of Linaro Ubuntu (11.10) modified for ARM or Android, both are downloadable from the project's site. Lately i've found a version of Ubuntu Server for ARM (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/arm/) and i wanted to know if it is compatible with all ARM devices, include the UDOO board. Also i wanted to know if the basic packages for the web server (like apache2, php5, mysql) and other packages (like mysql-connector c++, libcurl, g++) also work on ARM, under Ubuntu Server or under other Linux, like Linaro Ubuntu or Android. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

To install a Web Server on UDOO you can use Tasksel Installer:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

you can launch application with

```
sudo tasksel
```

Comment: But this package will install also apache2 and the other package?

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to install Ubuntu on the UDOO Board
http://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/20/installing-ubuntu-precise-12-04-on-a-udoo-quad

I just got my UDOO board today and I am going in that direction. So if Ubuntu runs nicely then most Ubuntu applications will run to.